# Android support library, optimal compile settings?

Tags: android, android-support-library

While importing support library in app gradle settings, what is the optimal configuration. For example-

If I just import support library like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

I find that the app works fine even if I just add appcompat code and do not add any recycler view import. I would like to know in what scenario will it be necessary?

Comment: Android Studio automatically take of care of importing minimal third parties lib and at the end proguard automatically removed unused part of libs So no need to worry about the size of APK.

Comment: That's good to know, thanks dex.

Comment: @dex How are unused libraries removed if the 65k multidex limit can easily be hit by including all the Google Play services?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am saying when you run your proguard to generate the final signed APK, it removed all unused part. < This is the role of Proguard >. http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: @dex the question has been edited, so I don't think it is asking about a minimal APK. It is asking why is only the  v7 library needed for RecyclerView and when to only use the specific RecyclerView dependency.

Comment: @cricket_007 : on then my answer is no longer valid. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @dex I edited the question to make it clearer. One of the goal is to have a minimal apk, but as pointed out that isn't the primary question.